# Did any Western country experiment with Japanese zoning laws or similar?

Tags: western-world, housing

> One of the most powerful policy tools available for Canada comes in
> the form of rezoning. At present, single family zoning is the primary
> form of zoning used in Canada, a fact that is especially notable in
> Canada’s major cities. As a result, Canadian cities have far lower
> densities than our international counterparts, leading to far higher
> prices as more land is needed to produce the same quantity of
> available homes. In Asia, where there is far less available land and
> much larger population, the challenge of ensuring housing access has
> long been an issue that governments have sought to address, often with
> substantial success along the way. Japan holds one of the best
> examples of this, with zoning policies being at the forefront of its
> housing system. As a result, Japan’s largest and most expensive
> cities, such as Tokyo and Osaka, are competitive in price with
> Canada’s most affordable cities, with prices often less than one third
> that of Toronto or Vancouver.
>
> While Canada has a strict and complicated system of zoning regulation,
> Japan’s system is simplified using only about a dozen zones. These
> zones have very wide varieties of usage options, and homes are allowed
> to be built in all of them except for heavy industrial zones. In
> nearly all of these zones, residential is defined very loosely,
> allowing for multi family homes and small apartment complexes to be
> built in the vast majority of available land.
>
> Restrictions on home size are much less onerous as well, with homes
> able use the vast majority of the lot on which they are built, with
> less clearance needed between the the home and other buildings or the
> street. Japan also applies its zoning system nationally, so laws are
> are universal across the country, without having new and different
> systems in each city and town as Canada does. Canada is also primarily
> using single family zoning, which restricts the type of homes being
> built to only the lowest density option, excluding the far more
> affordable options such as apartments or multi family constructions
> that would reduce cost and ensure far better usage of land.

https://www.canadahousingcrisis.com/making-housing-affordable/

Did any Western country experiment with Japanese zoning laws or similar? Canada has some of the most unaffordable housing markets in the world whereas Japan, which is a country with less land, has some of the most affordable housing markets in the world. I was wondering if any Western country implemented changes that are inspired by Japanese zoning laws in order to make housing more affordable.

Comment: I would ask the opposite, do any other countries have zoning laws like US and Canada have? I can't imagine terribly much neighbourhoods in the world without stray shop or apartment complex in the walking distance...

Comment: @alamar, Germany has quite complicated zoning laws. They *do* allow shops in mostly residential zones, but not necessarily malls or apartment complexes.

Comment: I'd argue that the US and Canadian-style zoning are the exception, not the rule. UK "zoning" (it's not called that here) sounds somewhat like what they do in Japan.

Comment: Maybe look at those "Western" countries where housing is affordable and then look if they have zoning laws and what kind of if they have. Maybe there is an even better solution than Japan and in Japan they simply somehow managed to build reliable multi story houses for a good price. Who says that zoning is the major problem. Also, Canada does seem to have a lot of space and those Canadians that have a home probably enjoy it quite well.

Comment: Our planning in Vancouver is indeed horrendous.  For all the pious homilies mouthed at each and every official pronouncement - "*this event is taking place on the unceded territories of the Squamish Nation*" - things like building towers for rent, *wholly* on tribal land, attract nuisance lawsuits by [NIMBYs](https://bc.ctvnews.ca/kitsilano-residents-still-trying-to-stop-access-road-for-senakw-development-1.6059537) protesting that it be *accessed* through a city-managed street.  Failed though, IIRC.  Another one: last resort NIMBY tactic was cyclist saying densification means dangerous roads.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff UK zoning and planning practices, from coverage of UK house prices, are hardly something to cite as an example of good policy ;-)  In fact, I suspect there is something ur-cultural going with the UK, Canada and New Zealand all struggling with affordability.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The housing crisis in the UK is primarily due to a shortage of homes, and not to do with zoning.